# Not working with method "UPDATE" in API REST MEAN + Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

```
exports.updateUsuarioByEmail = function (req, res) {
     console.log('updateUsuarioByEmail');
     console.log("PARAM ID" + req.params.email);
     return Usuario.find({ email: req.params.email }, function(err, usuario) {
        if(!usuario) {
            res.statusCode = 404;
            return res.send({ error: 'Not found' });
        }
        if (req.body.email != null) usuario.email = req.body.email;
        if (req.body.password != null) usuario.password = req.body.password;
        if (req.body.listaCardsSorting != null) usuario.listaCardsSorting = req.body.listaCardsSorting;

        return usuario.save(function(err) {
            if(!err) {
                console.log('Updated usuario');
                return res.send({ status: 'OK', usuario:usuario });
            } else {
                if(err.name == 'ValidationError') {
                    res.statusCode = 400;
                    res.send({ error: 'Validation error' });
                } else {
                    res.statusCode = 500;
                    res.send({ error: 'Server error' });
                }
                console.log('Internal error(%d): %s',res.statusCode,err.message);
            }
            res.send(usuario);
        });
    });
};
```

The error after to execute is :
[image]

I believe that the error is the line `"return usuario.save(function(err)..."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` return an `Array (list of documents)` . you can't do `save` on an array object. Instead try `findOne` if your `email` field is `unique`.

`findOne` returns a single `document`, so you can `save` that.

**Replace**

```
Usuario.find({ email: req.params.email }, function(err, usuario)
```

**with** :

```
Usuario.findOne({ email: req.params.email }, function(err, usuario)
```

Answer (score 0):

To update a model it's much easier to use the **[`findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)** update API. The method finds a matching document, updates it according to the update arg, passing any options, and returns the found document (if any) to the callback. The query executes immediately if callback is passed.

The syntax is:

```
Model#findOneAndUpdate([conditions], [doc], [options], [callback])
```

**Parameters**:

```
[conditions] <Object> - the query to match
[doc] <Object> - the document to update
[options] <Object> - update options
[callback] <Function> - callback
```

For example, the above function can be re-written to use the **[`findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)** method as:

```
exports.updateUsuarioByEmail = function (req, res) {
    console.log('updateUsuarioByEmail');
    console.log("PARAM ID" + req.params.email);

    var doc = {},
        conditions = { "email": req.params.email },
        options = { "new": true };

    if (req.body.email != null) doc.email = req.body.email;
    if (req.body.password != null) doc.password = req.body.password;
    if (req.body.listaCardsSorting != null) 
       doc.listaCardsSorting = req.body.listaCardsSorting;

    Usuario.findOneAndUpdate(
        conditions,
        doc,
        options,
        function(err, usuario) {
            if(!err) {
                console.log('Updated usuario');
                return res.send({ 
                    status: 'OK', 
                    usuario: usuario 
                });
            } else {
                if(err.name == 'ValidationError') {
                    res.statusCode = 400;
                    res.send({ error: 'Validation error' });
                } else {
                    res.statusCode = 500;
                    res.send({ error: 'Server error' });
                }
                console.log('Internal error(%d): %s',res.statusCode,err.message);
            }                       
        }
    )    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here remained the solution:

```
exports.updateUsuarioByEmail = function (req, res) {
console.log('updateUsuarioByEmail');

return Usuario.findOne({email: req.params.email}, function (err, usuario) {
    usuario.email = req.body.email || usuario.email;
    usuario.password = req.body.password || usuario.password;
    usuario.listaCardsSorting = req.body.listaCardsSorting || usuario.listaCardsSorting;

    return usuario.save(function (err) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log('Updated');
            return res.send({status: 'OK', usuario: usuario});
        } else {
            if (err.name == 'ValidationError') {
                res.statusCode = 400;
                res.send({error: 'Validation error'});
            } else {
                res.statusCode = 500;
                res.send({error: 'Server error'});
            }
            console.log('Internal error(%d): %s', res.statusCode, err.message);
        }
        res.send(usuario);
    });
});
```

};